# Create a value sequence based on a chronological object

Tags: r, datetime

I need to create a value sequence (named "seq" in the data frame below) based on a chronological object (here dates). To built a new sequence, the time interval between two dates needs to be strictly greater than 1 hour.

Here is an example

```
ID    date                 seq
A     2010-04-14 02:00:12   1
A     2010-04-14 02:00:12   1
A     2010-04-14 03:00:10   1
A     2010-04-14 03:00:10   1
A     2010-04-14 04:00:15   1
A     2010-04-14 04:00:15   1
A     2010-04-14 08:00:10   2
A     2010-04-14 08:00:10   2
B     2010-04-14 03:00:18   3
B     2010-04-14 03:00:18   3
B     2010-04-14 04:00:10   3
B     2010-04-14 04:00:10   3
B     2010-04-14 10:00:14   4
B     2010-04-14 10:00:14   4
B     2010-04-14 11:00:10   4
B     2010-04-14 11:00:10   4
```

**Data**

```
 tab <- data.frame(ID= rep(c("A","B"), each=8), date= as.POSIXct( c('2010-04-14 02:00:12','2010-04-14 02:00:12','2010-04-14 03:00:10', '2010-04-14 03:00:10','2010-04-14 04:00:15','2010-04-14 04:00:15','2010-04-14 08:00:10','2010-04-14 08:00:10','2010-04-14 03:00:18','2010-04-14 03:00:18','2010-04-14 04:00:10','2010-04-14 04:00:10','2010-04-14 10:00:14','2010-04-14 10:00:14','2010-04-14 11:00:10','2010-04-14 11:00:10'), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: Something like `1L+cumsum( diff(tab$date) > 60*60 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output seems incorrect because there is a 1 hour difference between "2010-04-14 03:00:10" and "2010-04-14 04:00:15" but your sequence doesn't increment. It's also not clear from your example whether or not the sequence should increment when `ID` changes.

Assuming `seq` should increment between "2010-04-14 03:00:10" and "2010-04-14 04:00:15" and the value in `ID` shouldn't affect `seq`, here's a solution:

```
tab$seq <- c(0, cumsum(abs(diff(tab$date)) > 3600)) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks very much Joshua. I obtained this error message:`Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "seq", value = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3,  : 
  replacement has 15 rows, data has 16`

Answer (score 1):

This line of code should serve the purpose:

```
tab$seq <- floor(as.numeric(tab$date-min(tab$date))/3600)
```